# Running old rails 2.x using docker, how to examine docker file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am trying to run this docker image I found, but I need to read the dockerfile to understand what it is expecting.

How can I see the docker file for: https://hub.docker.com/r/honigwasser/base-rails-ruby-2.3/

When I ran the docker image I was getting this error:

```
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_clean_rails_dir.sh...
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/01_read_secrets.sh...
Not reading secrets from Vault (READ_SECRETS_FROM_VAULT != true)
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 10
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to ssh inside the container? like `docker exec -it <container_id>`

if you want you can also try to copy the files from the container to your local like `docker cp <container_id>:/ .`